# Launching Web Browser in Android Application Occuring Error

Tags: android, android-manifest

Using below this code i m launching Web Browser But Cant

the code is:

```
Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("www.google.com");
Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH, uriUrl);  
startActivity(launchBrowser);  
finish();
```

i have also added menifest file internet permission and string
error is :Unexpectdly close.
pls

Comment: Please show the stack trace. It will be helpful.

Comment: exact what i do in eclipse. pls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public class Webview extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Uri uri= Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW , uri);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

This code will work.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` instead of `Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH`.

Comment: using this there is also same problem, Unexpectedly close

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, select the DDMS perspective, then click on Logcat, there you will see the details of exception, this details is called as Stack Trace. Show me that stack trace, please.

Comment: 01-16 12:58:46.804: INFO/dalvikvm(411): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

Comment: Look for the exception details. That will show you exactly what went wrong.